# Como executar um método diariamente de forma automatica

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, aplicação-web

Como eu posso criar uma rotina automática em minha aplicação para executar um determinado método todos os dias as 08:00 horas da manhã, com objetivo de atualizar um campo em uma tabela do meu banco de dados?

Comment: Eu uso o http://hangfire.io/ Muito fácil de usar, já uso a meses com 25 rotinas rodando, sem problema nenhum.